# Organizing external dependencies in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am relatively new to python and even newer to Lambda. I have created a lambda function that requires some external dependencies (`elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch-curator`).

My root folder is called `index_curator`, in which I have one single python file `main.py`. I installed the dependencies via `pip` as per Amazon's [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) e.g.

```
pip install elasticsearch elasticsearch-curator -t /path/to/index_curator
```

There are now many other files in this root directory and many child directories, which is not a surprise as these dependencies are quite large. For someone else looking at this package it would be difficult to differentiate between files I wrote and external dependencies. For example:

```
index_curator/
    dateutil/
    click/
    idna/
    main.py    <-- the only file I wrote
    README
    LICENSE
    six.py
    ...
```

Is there any way of shifting all these external dependencies into a sub-folder, e.g.

```
index_curator/
    /external/
        dateutil/
        click/
        idna/
        README
        LICENSE
        six.py
    main.py    <-- the only file I wrote
```

For completeness the imports in `main.py` are:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import curator
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating external dependencies from your code is definitely best practice. There are a number of ways you can achieve this in python.

By default, python searches for modules in the locations specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). To specify an additional location (i.e your `external` dependencies folder), this new location must be added to the python path. You can do this in your `main.py` as follows:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'external')))
```

Then you will be able to import all your dependencies as usual, since the interpreter will check the additional folder during runtime:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import curator
```

For more detail, check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Since your code will be a lambda function, you will always have one handler. But for a more generalised case, or if you start to write multiple files, and need to manage external dependencies in those as well - you can choose to maintain a `context.py` file, which sets the dependency path and all imports like so:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'external')))
import elasticsearch
import context
```

Then in your files, you can call them with:

```
from context.elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import context.curator
```